# Return 2 integers in a int function

Tags: java, android, function

I have two classes.

In the first class the integers `low` and `high` are needed.

In the second class I want to declare and change `low` and `high`.

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity { 
    int low = 0;
    int high = 101;
```

This works fine - but after the following function run through, the integers didn't change.

```
public int close (View v) {

    EditText low2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText high2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    int low = Integer.parseInt(low2.getText().toString());
    int high = Integer.parseInt(high2.getText().toString());
    high ++;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Low: " + low +" High: "+high, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   if (low > high) { //you can ignore it
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("False Numbers");
        builder.setMessage("You set the lower number higher than the higher one.");
        builder.show();
    } else {
        this.finish();
    }

    return low; //I want to return low AND high - but this command will not change low or high!
}
```

EDITED CODE:

```
public class HighAndLow{
    int high= 0;
    int low = 101;
}



public int[] close(View v){


    EditText low2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText high2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        low = Integer.parseInt(low2.getText().toString()); //cant find low now
        high = Integer.parseInt(high2.getText().toString()); //cant find high now
        high ++;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Low: " + low +" High: "+high,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();





   if (low > high) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("False Numbers");
        builder.setMessage("You set the lower number higher than the higher one.");
        builder.show();
    }
        else{

            this.finish();
        }




    return HighAndLow; //DONT WORK


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create the high and low integers as properties of your class? Then implement you're usual getters/setters. Set them via your close method, and get them from your second class when needed from your first instantiated class.

Comment: My first class can't see high and low - so the programm will not start.

Comment: I would suggest adding getter methods to your class. A getter method just returns a property of that class. Write one for each of your properties. Then when you need 'em just call int low = MyClass.GetLow()..or something like that.

Comment: Ohh, it's soo easy with getter and setter! THX!

Answer (score 2):

In Java (and Android), you can't return multiple values from a function. You can only return a single value. However, that single value can be an object that contains multiple fields.

You might consider creating a new class that contains both values. Something like this:

```
public class HighAndLow{
   int high;
   int low;
}
```

Then you can return an instance of this class from your method, and the calling code can access the high and low values that way.

In fact, Android already has a class that does this: [Range](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Range.html)

Comment: i understand your thinking, but i don't know how to write that.

I create the class HighAndLow - but how i have to change the int "high" and "low" in my close code and return them to HighAndLow?

im weired... i try to find a solution since hours.

Comment: @user1796692 You create an instance of HighAndLow (or better yet, Range) just like you would any other instance. If you're having trouble with this approach, then edit your question to include your updated code.

Comment: edited... i think i should go sleep and try this tomorrow, maybe i have a understanding for your explanation...

Comment: @user1796692 You're mixing up the different pieces of advice you're received. You're creating an array, but then returning a nonexistent HighAndLow. Choose one or the other. I would argue that using an array instead of the existing Range class is a pretty horrible idea, but it's really up to you.

Comment: So how i have to name my function and whats the right command for the return command? 

Now i changed from "public int[] close(View v){"  to "public class public class HighAndLow(View v){"

But Android Studio says that is wrong...

I dont understand you....

Comment: @user1796692 You need to take a step back and really try to understand some basic syntax. Try going through the basic Java tutorials on OOP until you understand how to create and instantiate a class.

Comment: I understand how to create classes, i don't understand how i work with an additional class with a new name you gave me...

Comment: @user1796692 You either need to create a class that contains high and low member variables, or you need to use the existing Range class.

Comment: The Range class is relly new (API 21) - i can only find the developer.android page. And this page sais me completly nothing about the Range.class in Android.

Answer (score -1):

It is not recommended and object oriented way, but if previous answers doesn't satisfy you can do it like this:

```
public int[] close (View v) {

    EditText low2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText high2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    int low = Integer.parseInt(low2.getText().toString());
    int high = Integer.parseInt(high2.getText().toString());
    high ++;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Low: " + low +" High: "+high, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   if (low > high) { //you can ignore it
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("False Numbers");
        builder.setMessage("You set the lower number higher than the higher one.");
        builder.show();
    } else {
        this.finish();
    }
    int[] values = {high,low};
    return values; //I want to return low AND high - but this command will not change low or high!
}
```

Then later

```
int[] myHighAndLow = close(someView);

//you need to remember what came first(First In First Out)
int high = myHighAndLow[0];
int low = myHighAndLow[1];
```

Comment: I don't understand down votes. He's asking for solutions, so here it is one. I made disclaimer it's not recommended.